# Understanding code flow with yield/generators

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator, yield, co

I've read over several examples of code using JavaScript generators [such as this one](https://medium.com/code-adventures/174f1fe66127).  The simplest generator-using block I can come up with is something like:

```
function read(path) {
    return function (done) {
        fs.readFile(path, "file", done);
    }
}

co(function *() {
    console.log( yield read("file") );
})();
```

This does indeed print out the contents of `file`, but my hangup is where `done` is called.  Seemingly, yield is syntactic sugar for wrapping what it returns to in a callback and assigning the result value appropriately (and at least in the case of `co`, throwing the error argument to the callback).  Is my understanding of the syntax correct?

What does `done` look like when `yield` is used?

Comment: Are you referring to `done` as used inside `read(path)`? I don't think it has anything to do with `yield` or generators specifically - it's part of the `co` library.

Answer (score 4):

> Seemingly, yield is syntactic sugar for wrapping what it returns to in a callback and assigning the result value appropriately (and at least in the case of co, throwing the error argument to the callback)

No, `yield` is no syntactic sugar. It's the core syntax element of generators. When that generator is instantiated, you can run it (by calling `.next()` on it), and that will return the value that was `return`ed or `yield`ed. When the generator was `yield`ed, you can continue it later by calling `.next()` again. The arguments to `next` will be the value that the `yield` expresion returns inside the generator.

*Only* in case of `co`, those async callback things (and [other things](https://github.com/visionmedia/co#yieldables)) are handled "appropriately" for what you would consider natural in an async control flow library.

> What does done look like when yield is used?

The `thread` function example from the [article that you read](https://medium.com/code-adventures/174f1fe66127) gives you a good impression of this:

```
function thread(fn) {
  var gen = fn();
  function next(err, res) {
    var ret = gen.next(res);
    if (ret.done) return;
    ret.value(next);
  }
  next();
}
```

In your code, `yield` does yield the value of the expression `read("file")` from the generator when it is ran. This becomes the `ret.val`, the result of `gen.next()`. To this, the `next` function is passed - a callback that will continue the generator with the `res`ult that was passed to it. In your generator code, it looks as if the `yield` expression returned this value.

An "unrolled" version of what happens could be written like this:

```
function fn*() {
    console.log( yield function (done) {
        fs.readFile("filepath", "file", done);
    } );
}
var gen = fn();
var ret1 = gen.next();
var callasync = ret1.value;
callasync(function next(err, res) {
    var ret2 = gen.next(res); // this now does log the value
    ret2.done; // true now
});
```

Comment: @Noseratio: Sorry, I don't really understand what you mean. Where is "assigning to `.value`" necessary, and what for? Isn't what is returned from a `yield` expression the argument that is passed to `.next()`? Feel free to edit my post if it needs correction.

Comment: @Bergi I'm still a bit confused; what is the actual *done* function?  Is that what is passed into `callasync`?  `yield` will emit the value of `ret2`?  Why?

Comment: @ExplosionPills: `ret1.value`/`callasync` is the function that takes the callback, it will be called with `next` as the `done` parameter, yes. The `yield` does emit the `res` (which was passed into `.next()`) as the `console.log` argument - that's how generators work.

Answer (score 2):

I posted a detailed explanation of how generators work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22523314/1768303).

In a simplified form, your code might look like this without `co` (untested):

```
function workAsync(fileName)
{
    // async logic
    var worker = (function* () {

        function read(path) {
            return function (done) {
                fs.readFile(path, "file", done);
            }
        }

        console.log(yield read(fileName));
    })();

    // driver
    function nextStep(err, result) {
        try {
            var item = err? 
                worker.throw(err):
                worker.next(result);
            if (item.done)
                return;
            item.value(nextStep);
        }
        catch(ex) {
            console.log(ex.message);
            return;
        }
    }

    // first step
    nextStep();
}

workAsync("file");
```

The driver part of `workAsync` asynchronously iterates through the generator object, by calling `nextStep()`.

Comment: @ExplosionPills, when `item.value(nextStep)` is called, `nextStep` is what corresponds to `done`, and `item.value` corresponds to the function which is returned by `read(path)`, when the latter gets called next to the `yield` statement, inside the `worker` generator.