# Why does ES2017 introduce async/await when ES6 already has generators?

Tags: javascript, async-await, generator, language-design, ecmascript-2017

When reading about `async` and `await`, I noticed that it's almost an equivalent of generator functions. Consider [this fragment from TypeScript Deep Dive](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/async-await.html):

> ### Async Await
>
> (...)
>
> ```
> // Not actual code. A thought experiment
> async function foo() {
>     try {
>         var val = await getMeAPromise();
>         console.log(val);
>     }
>     catch(err) {
>         console.log('Error: ', err.message);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> (...)
>
> #### Generated JavaScript
>
> You don't have to understand this, but it's fairly simple if you've read up on generators. The function `foo` can be simply wrapped up as follows:
>
> ```
> const foo = wrapToReturnPromise(function* () {
>     try {
>         var val = yield getMeAPromise();
>         console.log(val);
>     }
>     catch(err) {
>         console.log('Error: ', err.message);
>     }
> });
> ```
>
> where the `wrapToReturnPromise` just executes the generator function to get the `generator` and then use `generator.next()`, if the value is a `promise` it would `then`+`catch` the promise and depending upon the result call `genertor.next(result)` or `genertor.throw(error)`. That's it!

What is the reason that it ended up being "a new feature"? IMHO just using that `wrapToReturnPromise` function from some library would be just as good, while not contributing to the complexity of JavaScript itself.

Note: it's related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236960/es6-generators-are-they-really-an-alternative-to-async-await), but here I'm asking about the "why", not the "how". I try to understand the motivations.

Comment: `wrapToReturnPromise` is complicated (and often implemented wrong/overly naive) and incurs more overhead than necessary. An `async function` with `await` can be reasoned about and optimised better by the engine.

Comment: Real power comes from having *both*: [async generator functions](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration#async-generator-functions). That's just not possible with only generator syntax.

Comment: `async/await` is not part of ES7 (ES2016)! It will be part of this year's release, ES2017.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At first glance, the syntax is similar and you might assume the code would behave similarly -- but there are some key differences:

- **Say what you mean**: `function*` and `yield` mean something very different from `async function` and `await`, similar to how `Subclass.prototype = Object.create(Superclass.prototype); Subclass.prototype.constructor = Subclass` is different from `class Subclass extends Superclass`
- **Operator precedence**: You can do `await a + await b` to mean `(await a) + (await b)`, but `yield a + yield b` means `yield (a + (yield b))`
- **Future development**: `async/await` pave the way for some really interesting work with optimistic transactional locking and speculative execution, since they are (as noted in this thread) explicit markers of atomicity boundaries
- **Other arguments**: There are also many counter arguments to `async/await` -- [including many people that say that generators are just plain 'better'](https://spion.github.io/posts/es7-async-await-step-in-the-wrong-direction.html) and that `async/await` is going in the wrong direction.

*Summarized shamelessly from the [ES discussion site](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/does-async-await-solve-a-real-problem).  I encourage you to read the entire thread as it has some very interesting discussion on the subject.*