# Can ES6 generators yield the data passed normally to a callback/promise?

Tags: javascript, generator, ecmascript-6

So if you have a function like this:

```
function* queryDB(query){
    yield db.collection.find(query);
}
```

From what I understand, it will yield what `db.collection.find()` returns, so say it returns a promise, then queryDB() should return an iterable with a promise as a value in it, so something like co can be used to consolidate promises yielded into a single promise.  Is there a way to yield what would be passed to that promise, without modifying `db.collection.find()` so that I can just use a for-of loop to iterate over the results from the database?

**TO BE CLEAR**

I am asking if I can get the arguments that are passed to the function passed into the `.then()` of a promise.  As in

```
queryDB().then(function(<values>)
```

but instead I yield an iterator of the `<values>`.

Comment: [No](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29281361/1048572)

Comment: `for...of` is synchronous. Asynchronous methods cannot be processed synchronously.

Comment: ... ummm I don't think you read my question right... I can *iterate over the result* of the generator.

Comment: @Bergi I'm asking something rather different than what you claim is a duplicate.  I'm asking to get the values from db.collection.find() as oppose to wrapping promises.

Comment: If you mean that you want to use `for (value of queryDB())`, then that sounds exactly like the duplicate (if not, please [edit] your question and add the code that you'd expect to use). It's impossible to unwrap promises and make them synchronous. You can only use `then`, or use `yield` inside a generator that is run by `co` or similar.

Comment: @Bergi did you not read " Is there a way to yield what would be passed to that promise, without modifying db.collection.find() so that I can just use a for-of loop to iterate over the results from the database?" Keywords being passed to the promise.  I think it's pretty clear.

Comment: @DaveWallace: Sorry, no, it's not clear to me, as you cannot "pass" anything to a promise - a promise is a value, not a function. So without knowing what you want to yield, I don't understand the first half of that sentence, and the second half sounds like a dupe of the questions I linked.

Comment: @Bergi it's pretty clear you do understand you're just being uptight about it. But whatever, this is why SO is on a downturn, people abusing their power.  But I edited it anyway.

Comment: @Bergi sounds like you're being a little harsh on this guy, I understood this quite clearly, and I agree it is not a dupe.

Comment: @DaveWallace: So you want to yield the result values of the promise, ok. Then the answer is *no* (as outlined in the linked posts), as those results come in asynchronously and you cannot access them without waiting.

Comment: @ChristianGrabowski: Sorry if I came off as harsh, but I really think he's asking for the same thing as the linked questions. Regardless, I've reopened the question so you may post your answer.

Comment: You want to get the values passed as arguments to the `then` callback. What I'm not sure I understand: Where do you want them? inside the generator (`queryDB`), so you can yield them? Or do you want the aformentioned `then` callback to yield an interator of the values? (I don't actually have a solution or anything, I just don't fully understand the question)

Comment: You should write how you want to use `queryDB`. How interface will look like?

Comment: @nils the first option is what I want.

Comment: @DaveWallace so, inside generator queryDb?

Comment: @DmitryYaremenko I am asking: Is it possible to return an iterator that contains the arguements thatdb.collection.find() returns.  So probably an error arguement and the result from the database.  Which is to say, I *am not yielding the promise being returned from db.collection.find()*

Comment: @DaveWallace `function* queryDB(query) { db.collection.find(query).then(function(values) { yield values; }); }` - something like that ? No. (added case in the answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can do** this only inside generator.

```
function* queryDB(query) {
  // Here is synchrous-like code!
  var rows = yield db.collection.find(query);

  var sum = 0;

  // Use the rows synchrously
  for (var x of rows) {
    sum += x;
  }

  return sum;
}

var sumPromise = doM(queryDB('query example'));

sumPromise.then(console.log.bind(console));
```

See [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcxw97a/) (I recommend to play with this and see what it returns in different cases and it will be clear).

---

And you **can't do**:

```
for (var x of db.collection.find(query))
  ...
```

Or:

```
for (var x of queryDB('some query'))
  ...
```

It will be like:

```
for (var x of (new Promise(...)))
  ...
```

Your generator / wrapper will return a promise. You can do only `then` with it.

---

And you **can not do**:

```
function* queryDB(query) {
  db.collection.find(query).then(function(values) {
      yield values;
  });
}
```

**Explanation of the last:**

How compiler will see this code:

```
function* queryDB(query) {
  db.collection.find(query).then(anonymousFunction);
}
```

And `anonymousFunction` is not a generator, so you can't write `yield` there. Also, `Promise` in `then` doesn't expect a generator.

On the other side if you want to use `for (var x in queryDB())` compiler expects to return an array from `queryDB()`. If your `queryDB()` is asynchrous it will return a Promise-like interface.

If you switch to more *functional style*, you can write:

```
 forEach(queryDB(), function(item) {
    // action on item
 });
```

You can do `reduce` or `map` implementation if you now that your promised value is an array. But in this case you don't need a generator.

---

`doM` implementation:

```
function doM(gen) {
  function step(value) {
    var result = gen.next(value);
    if (result.done) {
      return result.value;
    }
    return result.value.then(step);
  }
  return step();
}
```

Source: [Monads in JavaScript](https://curiosity-driven.org/monads-in-javascript).

`forEach` implementation:

```
function forEach(promise, callback) {
  return promise.then(function(iterable) {
    for (var x of iterable) {
      callback(x);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what the OP is already doing. Only by using `co`, instead of a hand-written `doM`.

Comment: yes, I'm asking how can I yield the arguements passed into that promise.

Comment: Edited an answer, not sure if I correctly understood the question. Hope this edition will be more helpful to explain the technique. Agree with Bergi that `for x of queryDB()` is not possible outside the generator (wrapper).

Comment: Can you just condense this to `function* queryDB(query) {
  db.collection.find(query).then(function(values) {
      yield values;
  });
}` not being possible?

Comment: @DaveWallace added to the answer