# Return only certain yield in generator(iterator) function

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I would like to do something like this.

```
function* iterateRecord() {

    const db = yield MongoClient.connect('');

    const collection = db.collection('');

    const query = {}


    const cursor = collection.find(query);

    while (yield cursor.hasNext()) {

        const bsonObject = yield cursor.next();
    }
}

for(record of iterateRecord())
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Now as you can see this will not work the db yield will be the first iteration of the for. So what I would like to do is only return the yield at the cursor.next.

Is this possible? I have tried a few things but i always get to the multiple yield that not part of the iteration.

thanks

Comment: please have a look, what [`yield`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) is doing. it pauses the function and returns the value.

Comment: Yes I understand what yield is doing. The reason i have the yield in db and in hasNext is because i don't want to have to deal with promises or callbacks.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29281361/1048572)

Comment: hmmm nope :-). I have a case where the 'answer' will work but not this instance and its all 'yield cursor.hasNext' fault.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing two different things here: (1) js generators and (2) usage of js generators to emulate async/await.

There are a number of libraries for (2) like [co](https://github.com/tj/co) or [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.coroutine.html), but all of them expect that you're going to `yield` promises.

It will not work with `for` loop for sure because it doesn't wait promises to resolve and doesn't return the result back to generator.

Comment: I have tried something like this but i keep getting stuck on 

yield cursor.hasNext()

Comment: Sorry. I didn't notice that cursor.hasNext().