# Asynchronously working generator function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, generator

I want to have a JS generator function that returns a series of some stuff, let's say its suggestions for dinner. It knows names of some dishes, but if I don't like any of them, it will need to fetch more suggestions from a remote server. So I'd like this to work:

```
const dishSuggestions = function* (){
  yield "pancakes";
  yield "pizza";
  fetchMealSuggestions().then(suggestions => {  // Or even better await.
    for (const suggestion of suggestions)
      yield suggestion;
  });
};
```

This won't work obviously because I cannot yield from an inner function. So my question is: how to get that behaviour? Can I? Or is this the wrong tool?

Comment: Have a look at [How can I convert this async callback to a generator?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29280189/1048572) - the answer is No. Promises and Iterators can (currently) not be mixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, what you want in this situation is an async generator that contains an async iterator.

Here's how that would look:

```
// Note the * after "function"
async function* dishSuggestions() {
  yield "pancakes";
  yield "pizza";

  // async iteration: yield each suggestion, one after the other
  for await (const meal of fetchMealSuggestions()) {
    yield meal;
  }
}

async function logDishes() {
  for await (const dish of dishSuggestions()) {
    console.log(dish);
  }  
}

logDishes();
```

Here's a [working transpilled demo with Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=env%2Ces2015%2Ces2015-loose%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=%2F%2F%20Note%20the%20*%20after%20%22function%22%0Aasync%20function*%20dishSuggestions()%20%7B%0A%20%20yield%20%22pancakes%22%3B%0A%20%20yield%20%22pizza%22%3B%0A%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20async%20streams%0A%20%20for%20await%20(const%20meal%20of%20fetchMealSuggestions())%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20yield%20meal%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aasync%20function%20dishes()%20%7B%0A%20%20for%20await%20(const%20dish%20of%20dishSuggestions())%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(dish)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%20%20%0A%7D%0A%0Adishes()%0A%0Aasync%20function%20*%20fetchMealSuggestions()%20%7B%0A%20%20yield%20'apples'%3B%0A%20%20yield%20'oranges'%3B%0A%7D).

Note that `fetchMealSuggestions` must also return an async iterator for the async iteration to work.

That being said, this is still a brand-new feature that just started shipping with each browser.

[More details](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/async-iterators-and-generators/)

For now, take a look at the [question Bergi recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280189/how-can-i-convert-this-async-callback-to-a-generator) in the comments.

Comment: This is a nice solution.

Comment: I look forward to async generators becoming the norm in APIs, they're a very powerful and concise way of bringing stream-based operations into the realm of promises.