# ECMA6 generators: yield promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

As I understand it ECMA6 generators are supposed to be able to yield to a function that returns a promise, eventually returning the resolved/rejected. Making the code read more like synchronous code, and avoiding callback hell.

I am using node.js v0.12.2 with --harmony and the following code.

```
var someAsyncThing = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve("I'm Resolved!");
  });
};

someAsyncThing().then(function(res) {console.log(res);});
// Works as expected: logs I'm Resolved!

function* getPromise() {
    var x = yield someAsyncThing();
    console.log("x: " + x); // Fails x undefined
}

var y = getPromise();
console.log(y); // returns {}

console.log(y.next());
// Fails: logs { value: {}, done: false }
```

I've based the code off of the few examples I have been able to find online.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should read this article: http://davidwalsh.name/async-generators

Comment: I did read that, and this code is partially based off his example.  It doesn't work.

Comment: You are missing the most important part from that article, the `runGenerator` function.

Comment: runGenerator is just his own decorator and unneeded.  The very first example he shows doesn't require it, and he says so.  No other examples out there require anything else to use generators in this way either.

Comment: Fair enough. See my answer.

Comment: @Ryhnn What is expected result ?

Answer (score 8):

> As I understand it ECMA6 generators are supposed to be able to yield to a function that returns a promise, eventually returning the resolved/rejected.

No, that's not their purpose. ES6 generators are supposed to provide a simple way for writing iterators - each call to a generator function produces an iterator. An iterator is just a sequence of values - like an array, but consumed dynamically and produced lazily.

Now, generators can be *abused* for asynchronous control flow, by producing a sequence of promises that is consumed asynchronously and advancing the iterator with the results of each awaited promise. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23554399/1048572) for an explanation without promises.

So what your code is missing is the consumer that actually waits for the promises and advances your generator. Usually you'd use a dedicated library (like [co](https://github.com/tj/co) or [task.js](http://taskjs.org/)), or one of the helper functions that many promise libraries provide ([Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#generators), [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#generators), [when](https://github.com/cujojs/when/blob/master/docs/api.md#es6-generators), …), but for the purposes of this answer I'll show a simplified one:

```
function run(gf) {
    let g = gf();
    return Promise.resolve(function step(v) {
         var res = g.next(v);
         if (res.done) return res.value;
         return res.value.then(step);
    }());
}
```

Now with this function you can actually "execute" your `getPromise` generator:

```
run(getPromise).then(console.log, console.error);
```

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr:** The promise yielded by the generator has to move the generator forward.

---

If you look at first examples in http://davidwalsh.name/async-generators, you will notice that the async function actually moves the iterator forward:

```
function request(url) {
    // this is where we're hiding the asynchronicity,
    // away from the main code of our generator
    // `it.next(..)` is the generator's iterator-resume
    // call
    makeAjaxCall( url, function(response){
        it.next( response );               // <--- this is where the magic happens
    } );
    // Note: nothing returned here!
}
```

But since you are working with promises, we can improve on that, a little bit. `y.next().value` returns a promise, and you'd have to listen to that promise. So instead of writing `console.log(y.next())`, you'd write:

```
var promise = y.next().value;
promise.then(y.next.bind(y)); // or promise.then(function(v) { y.next(v); });
```

[Babel demo](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=false&code=var%20someAsyncThing%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise(function(resolve%2C%20reject)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20resolve(%22I'm%20Resolved!%22)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%2F%2FsomeAsyncThing().then(function(res)%20%7Bconsole.log(res)%3B%7D)%3B%0A%2F%2F%20Works%20as%20expected%3A%20logs%20I'm%20Resolved!%0A%0Afunction*%20getPromise()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20var%20x%20%3D%20yield%20someAsyncThing()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%22x%3A%20%22%20%2B%20x)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Fails%20x%20undefined%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20y%20%3D%20getPromise()%3B%0Aconsole.log(y)%3B%20%2F%2F%20returns%20%7B%7D%0A%0Avar%20promise%20%3D%20y.next().value%3B%0Apromise.then(y.next.bind(y))%3B)

Of course this not very practical, because now you cannot access the next yielded value and you don't know when the generator will be done. However, you could write a recursive function which takes care of that. That's what `runGenerator` introduced later in this article takes care of.

Answer (score 0):

Modern JavaScript has async/await syntax. For example:

```js
function sleep(delay) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(resolve, delay);
    } );
};

(async function () {
    console.log('one');
    await sleep(1000);
    console.log('two');
    await sleep(1000);
    console.log('three');
})();
```

Prior to async/await syntax, you had the option of using Promises with function generators that yield promises. To do this, if you put the above code into https://babeljs.io and enable the babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator it will produce the following code snippet.

```js
function sleep(delay) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(resolve, delay);
    } );
}

_asyncToGenerator(function *() {
    console.log('one');
    yield sleep(1000);
    console.log('two');
    yield sleep(1000);
    console.log('three');    
})();

function _asyncToGenerator(fn) {
    return function() {
        var self = this,
        args = arguments
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var gen = fn.apply(self, args)
            function _next(value) {
                asyncGeneratorStep(gen, resolve, reject, _next, _throw, "next", value)
            }
            function _throw(err) {
                asyncGeneratorStep(gen, resolve, reject, _next, _throw, "throw", err)
            }
            _next(undefined)
        })
    }
}

function asyncGeneratorStep(gen, resolve, reject, _next, _throw, key, arg) {
    try {
        var info = gen[key](arg)
        var value = info.value
    } catch (error) {
        reject(error)
        return
    }
    if (info.done) {
        resolve(value)
    } else {
        Promise.resolve(value).then(_next, _throw)
    }
}
```

N.B. this is a summary of a larger post here [ES6 asynchronous generator result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34693721/es6-asynchronous-generator-result/73452997#73452997)