# ES6 asynchronous generator result

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-6, generator, ecmascript-next

ES6 has [generators that return iterators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators):

```
function* range(n) {
    for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        yield i;
    }
}

for (let x of range(10)) {
    console.log(x);
}
```

There is a proposal for asynchronous functions that return [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```
async function f(x) {
    let y = await g(x);
    return y * y;
}

f(2).then(y => {
    console.log(y);
});
```

So what happens if I combine the two, like this:

```
async function* ag(n) {
    for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
         yield i;
    }
}
```

What does it return? Is it `Promise<Iterator<Item>>`? `Iterator<Promise<Item>>`? Something else? How do I consume it? I imagine there should be a corresponding `for` loop, what will iterate over its result asynchronously, something like:

```
for (await let x of ag(10)) {
    console.log(x);
}
```

which waits for each item to become available before trying to access the next one.

Comment: Hmmmm, too early to answer this question, as `async/await` proposal is not yet approved.

Comment: An async iterator - there's a sp c - I'm on mobile but it's already decided for the most part. It's a generator whose `next` returns a promise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## `Promise<Iterator<Item>>` or `Iterator<Promise<Item>>`?

Neither. It's still not approved, but current implementations return something else. Kris Kowal has [written an about async generators](https://github.com/kriskowal/gtor#asynchronous-generator-functions), and references [Jafar Husain's AsyncGenerator proposal for ES7](https://github.com/jhusain/asyncgenerator). **EDIT**: We have [tc39 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration) and [babel support](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-syntax-async-generators)!

Let's define some types (simplified):

```
interface Iterator<T> {
  Iteration<T> next();
}

type Iteration<T> = { done: boolean, value: T }
```

We are looking for something that can be used like this:

```
for (;;) {
    var iteration = await async_iterator.next();
    if (iteration.done) {
        return iteration.value;
    } else {
        console.log(iteration.value);
    }
}
```

An `Iterator<Promise<T>>` produces synchronous iterations, whose values are Promises. It could be used like this:

```
for (;;) {
    var iteration = iterator_promise.next();
    if (iteration.done) {
        return await iteration.value;
    } else {
        console.log(await iteration.value);
    }
}
```

A `Promise<Iterator<T>>` is just a regular synchronous iterator, starting in the future:

```
var iterator = await promise_iterator;
for (;;) {
    var iteration = iterator.next();
    if (iteration.done) {
        return iteration.value;
    } else {
        console.log(iteration.value);
    }
}
```

So neither `Iterator<Promise<T>>` nor `Promise<Iterator<T>>` was suitable. Currently async generators return `AsyncIterator`s instead:

```
interface AsyncIterator<T> {
  Promise<Iteration<T>> next();
}
```

Which perfectly makes sense. Moving to the next element of the iterator is the asynchronous operation, and this can be used exactly like we wanted.

## How do I consume Async Generators?

<s>Babeljs.io already compiles async generators. [Babeljs.io/repl example](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=function%20delay(timeout%2C%20val)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise(resolve%20%3D%3E%20setTimeout(resolve%2C%20timeout%2C%20val))%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aasync%20function*%20asyncGenerator()%20%7B%0A%20%20for%20(var%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%205%3B%20i%2B%2B)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20await%20delay(500)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20yield%20i%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aasync%20function%20forAwait(iter%2C%20fn)%20%7B%0A%20%20for%20(%3B%3B)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20iteration%20%3D%20await%20iter.next()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(iteration.done)%20return%20iteration.value%3B%0A%20%20%20%20await%20fn(iteration.value)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aasync%20function%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log('Started')%3B%0A%20%20await%20forAwait(asyncGenerator()%2C%20async%20item%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20await%20delay(100)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(item)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20console.log('End')%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Amain()%3B)</s>:

**EDIT**: No preset on babeljs.io compiles async generators since babel 6, `babel-plugin-transform-regenerator` supports it with `{asyncGenerators:true}` option.

**EDIT**: see [`transform-async-generator-functions`](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-async-generator-functions) babel 6 plugin.

```
function delay(timeout, val) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeout, val));
}

async function* asyncGenerator() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    await delay(500);
    yield i;
  }
}

async function forAwait(iter, fn) {
  for (;;) {
    let iteration = await iter.next();
    if (iteration.done) return iteration.value;
    await fn(iteration.value);
  }
}


async function main() {
  console.log('Started');
  await forAwait(asyncGenerator(), async item => {
    await delay(100);
    console.log(item);
  });
  console.log('End');
}

main();
```

There is a proposal for a convenient `for await` loop for async iterators (described at [Async iteration](https://github.com/zenparsing/async-iteration/)):

```
for await (let line of readLines(filePath)) {
    print(line);
}
```

**Update:**

Unfortunately, `async-await` didn't become a part of [*ECMAScript 2016*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values). At least `await` is mentioned a reserved word for future use.

**Update:**

Related proposals:

- https://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/
- https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration

Comment: But how to "delegate yield" an async generator? Neither `yield* await` nor `await yield*` fits.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph In the proposal it is mentioned: `The behavior of yield* is modified to support delegation to async iterators.`. But one might ask how do you then delegate to regular generator? Ultimately you can always use a yield in a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Lots have changed since this post was written. `Promises`, `iterators/generators` and `async/await` syntax are all part of the standard. Let's take a look at the evolution of running a simple async operation (e.g. `setTimeout`) over the different methods.

Let's consider a simple Promise wrapper to the `setTimeout` function. Then, we can implement a simple Promise chain to `console.log` messages with a sleep delay.

```js
function sleep(delay) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(resolve, delay);
    } );
}

console.log('one');
sleep(1000)
.then( function () {
    console.log('two');
    return sleep(1000);
} )
.then( function () {
    console.log('three');
} );
```

Now let's consider rewriting the above Promise chain using async/await syntax:

```js
function sleep(delay) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(resolve, delay);
    } );
}

(async function () {
    console.log('one');
    await sleep(1000);
    console.log('two');
    await sleep(1000);
    console.log('three');
})();
```

Very nice. Prior to new standards, people were using https://babeljs.io to help transpile from the newer JavaScript standards to an earlier version by rewriting `await/async` with iterator/generator syntax:

```js
function sleep(delay) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(resolve, delay);
    } );
}

_asyncToGenerator(function *() {
    console.log('one');
    yield sleep(1000);
    console.log('two');
    yield sleep(1000);
    console.log('three');    
})();

function _asyncToGenerator(fn) {
    return function() {
        var self = this,
        args = arguments
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var gen = fn.apply(self, args)
            function _next(value) {
                asyncGeneratorStep(gen, resolve, reject, _next, _throw, "next", value)
            }
            function _throw(err) {
                asyncGeneratorStep(gen, resolve, reject, _next, _throw, "throw", err)
            }
            _next(undefined)
        })
    }
}

function asyncGeneratorStep(gen, resolve, reject, _next, _throw, key, arg) {
    try {
        var info = gen[key](arg)
        var value = info.value
    } catch (error) {
        reject(error)
        return
    }
    if (info.done) {
        resolve(value)
    } else {
        Promise.resolve(value).then(_next, _throw)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking:
The Iterator-functions have no return-value, so it makes no sense to make them async.
Then there is this conceptual gap between these two approaches.
- Iterators are pull-based: You call the iterator and invoke the computation of a new Value
- Promises are push-based: The Promise pushes a result to it's listener. (once or never)

And while it would make sence in some cases to create an `Iterator<Pomise<Item>>`

```
function* f(g){
    for(...){
        let y = await g();
        yield y;
    }
}
```

I can't think of any case where it would make sense to wrap an Iterator into a Promise. since there is nothing async in Instantiating an Iterator from it's definition.