# async/await vs combining generators and promises?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, generator

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

> The purpose of async/await functions is to simplify the behavior of
>   using promises synchronously and to perform some behavior on a group
>   of Promises. Just as Promises are similar to structured callbacks,
>   async/await is similar to combining generators and promises.

I understand basic concepts of async/await, generators and promises. However, I don't fully understand what it means by saying **async/await is similar to combining generators and promises.**

So async/await simplify what generators and promises can do together? Any example?

Comment: Read [this article](https://medium.com/@rdsubhas/es6-from-callbacks-to-promises-to-generators-87f1c0cd8f2e) to understand what is difference between promises, generators and `async/await`.

Comment: Generators were used [together with an intricate helper function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23554399/1048572) as a hack to do what `async`/`await` does now. I would recommend to avoid this comparison however, it should be seen as nothing but a historic artefact. I think MDN needs a good edit…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes, you're right.** An example with a generator and promises first:

```
function *gen () {
    const promiseValue = yield new Promise((resolve) => resolve(42));
    console.log(promiseValue);
}

// .. and at some other context using '*gen'

const iterator = gen();
const { value: promise } = iterator.next(); // Promise (42)

promise.then((resolvedValue) => iterator.next(resolvedValue)); // logs 42
```

This generator yields a `Promise` to the outside world, one whose value we pass back into the generator by passing it as an argument to the `iterator.next` call, once that promise resolves.

This pattern at least intersects with what is said to be a *task*. The disadvantage of this is that we DO have to call `next` manually on the iterator, every time a yielded promise resolves. That's where `async await` comes in:

```
async function task() {
    const promiseValue = await new Promise((resolve) => resolve(42));
    console.log(promiseValue);
}
```

And that's all there is to it. An async function will pause until a promise expression preceded by the `await` keyword resolves, and the expression will evaluate to an automatic *unwrap* of the promise - i.e. its final value.

Then the await expression's result (`42`, in our case) will be assigned to `promiseValue`, like `yield` works as well. This all happens before the function continues its execution to the next statement.

*This is essentially equal behaviour as the above snippet with the generator.*

Although in my experience this example seems to be the most common use-case for both generators and async functions, one where async/await is definitely the cleaner approach, generators do have some really strong powers that async/await does not have in the same way (but that is another topic).

Comment: I disagree with the added opinion at the end. The most common use-case for generators are for generating infinite iterators and implementing lazily evaluated queries.

Comment: Great, thanks for setting this straight, Jeffrey. I stumbled upon this in the review queue Thanks for noting @PhiQuangPhuoc.